# numpy, taking array difference of their intersection

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have multiple numpy arrays and I want to create new arrays doing something that is like an XOR ... but not quite.

My input is two arrays, array1 and array2.
My output is a modified (or new array, I don't really care) version of array1.

The modification is elementwise, by doing the following:

1.)  If either array has 0 for the given index, then the index is left unchanged.
2.)  If array1 and array2 are nonzero, then the modified array is assigned the value of array1's index subtracted by array2's index, down to a minimum of zero.

Examples:

```
array1:  [0, 3, 8, 0]
array2:  [1, 1, 1, 1]
output:  [0, 2, 7, 0]


array1:  [1, 1, 1, 1]
array2:  [0, 3, 8, 0]
output:  [1, 0, 0, 1]

array1:  [10, 10, 10, 10]
array2:  [8, 12, 8, 12]
output:  [2, 0, 2, 0]
```

I would like to be able to do this with say, a single numpy.copyto statement, but I don't know how.  Thank you.

edit:

it just hit me.  could I do:

```
new_array = np.zeros(size_of_array1)
numpy.copyto(new_array, array1-array2, where=array1>array2)
```

Edit 2:  Since I have received several answers very quickly I am going to time the different answers against each other to see how they do.  Be back with results in a few minutes.

Okay, results are in:

array of random ints 0 to 5, size = 10,000, 10 loops

1.)using my np.copyto method

2.)using clip

3.)using maximum

```
0.000768184661865
0.000391960144043
0.000403165817261
```

Kasramvd also provided some useful timings below

Comment: Copy + boolean indexing and `np.clip`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple subtraction and clipping the result with zero as the `min`:

```
(arr1 - arr2).clip(min=0)
```

Demo:

```
In [43]: arr1 = np.array([0,3,8,0]); arr2 = np.array([1,1,1,1])

In [44]: (arr1 - arr2).clip(min=0)
Out[44]: array([0, 2, 7, 0])
```

On large arrays it's also faster than `maximum` approach:

```
In [51]: arr1 = np.arange(10000); arr2 = np.arange(10000)

In [52]:  %timeit np.maximum(0, arr1 - arr2)
22.3 µs ± 1.77 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [53]: %timeit (arr1 - arr2).clip(min=0)
20.9 µs ± 167 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [54]: arr1 = np.arange(100000); arr2 = np.arange(100000)

In [55]:  %timeit np.maximum(0, arr1 - arr2)
671 µs ± 5.69 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [56]: %timeit (arr1 - arr2).clip(min=0)
648 µs ± 4.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Note that if it's possible for `arr2` to have negative values you should consider using an `abs` function on `arr2` to get the expected result:

```
(arr1 - abs(arr2)).clip(min=0)
```

Comment: How does this work if `array2` has negative values at those positions where `array1` has zeros? I can't find any reference in the question that says arrays are non-negative... CC: @TravisBlack

Comment: @AGNGazer That's a good question. In that case it will choose positive version of those negative numbers. But based on what OP says it should return 0. let me update the answer.

Comment: I think @TravisBlack should clarify this. If `array2` is non-negative, this is a very elegant answer.

Comment: @AGNGazer Yes, it'd be better. However I updated the answer with a workaround in case OP wants the same behavior in both cases.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [73]: np.maximum(0,np.array([0,3,8,0])-np.array([1,1,1,1]))
Out[73]: array([0, 2, 7, 0])
```

This doesn't explicitly address

> If either array has 0 for the given index, then the index is left unchanged.

but the results match for all examples:

```
In [74]: np.maximum(0,np.array([1,1,1,1])-np.array([0,3,8,0]))
Out[74]: array([1, 0, 0, 1])
In [75]: np.maximum(0,np.array([10,10,10,10])-np.array([8,12,8,12]))
Out[75]: array([2, 0, 2, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first simply subtract the arrays and then use [**`boolean array indexing`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) on the subtracted result to assign 0 where there are negative values as in:

```
# subtract
In [43]: subtracted = arr1 - arr2

# get a boolean mask by checking for < 0
# index into the array and assign 0
In [44]: subtracted[subtracted < 0] = 0

In [45]: subtracted
Out[45]: array([0, 2, 7, 0])
```

---

Applying the same for the other inputs specified by OP:

```
In [46]: arr1 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
    ...: arr2 = np.array([0, 3, 8, 0])

In [47]: subtracted = arr1 - arr2
In [48]: subtracted[subtracted < 0] = 0

In [49]: subtracted
Out[49]: array([1, 0, 0, 1])
```

And for the third input arrays:

```
In [50]: arr1 = np.array([10, 10, 10, 10])
    ...: arr2 = np.array([8, 12, 8, 12])

In [51]: subtracted = arr1 - arr2
In [52]: subtracted[subtracted < 0] = 0

In [53]: subtracted
Out[53]: array([2, 0, 2, 0])
```

Comment: very strange that people downvote working solutions. Leaving a comment would have been nicer.